# Empty List with size 2

Tags: python, list

Whenever i run the following code and insert no element in the list it prints out 2 as output which is the length of the list, so why an empty list has size 2 instead of 0 since it contains no element?

```
a = list(map(int, input().split()))
print(len(str(a)))
```

Comment: `str` of an empty list is `"[]"` which has a `len` of `2`.

Comment: The length of the list is `len(a)`.  What you are printing is the length of the string representation of the list (i.e. two square bracket characters)

Answer (score 1):

Why did you convert the list to a string? Try this instead:

```
a = list(map(int, input().split()))
print(len(a))
=> 0
```

In your code, you were taking the length of a *string* with two brackets in it, not of an empty list! This is what you were doing:

```
print(len('[]'))
=> 2
```